# Cocoa Bindings: NSStrings and NSTextFields?

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsstring, nstextfield

I've managed to bind the value of an NSString to an NSTextField, but I wish to do the opposite. My goal is to be able to have an NSString that updates with a changing NSTextField.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using the word "bind" properly (a lot of people don't). If you've bound a string property to the value of the text field, the binding goes both ways -- if you type something in the text field, that will be the new value of the string.  Conversely, if you change the value of the string in code, it will change what appears in the text field.

Perhaps you should post what you've managed to do.